# Other ways for zoom-in zoom-out in Android WebView?

Tags: android, webview

My actual task is to have zoom in zoom out for the WebView, but I don't want to scale images.

Are there ways to do that?

Answer (score 3):

setting the default zoom controls is very easy:

```
browser.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

where `browser` is the name of your webview. This alows for double tap, pinch-to-zoom and standard zoom buttons to work out of the box.
A short google search should help you find the scaling part as well. Good luck

Comment: Hi Matt i have used your code but still does not working just look below site